# When returning a function, is the value computed first before returning?

Tags: python, return

I'm trying to implement a function with multiple stages with potential skips, but I'm not sure if my method is being efficient.  The question is whether the values used in computing Part 1 will be carried on to the next stages. For example, lets say the 4th stage looks like:

```
define stage4(x):
  # Part 1. Computations of stage 4
  ...
  ...
  # Part 2. Computations are done, now ask user which stage is next
  nextstage = int(input("Go to which stage?"))
  if (nextstage == 5):
    return stage5(x)
  elif (nextstage == 7):
    return stage7(x)
  else:
    print("error, try again")
    return stage4()
```

My question then, is if I call in stage5 through this code (by inputting "5" on console), would stage5 occur before or after stage4 is exited?  I don't want stage4 to wait for the return value of stage5; I want to leave stage4 completely after stage5 is called.

My concern is that since I have multiple stages repeatedly, if I am not properly exiting the previous stage before calling the next stage I will be carrying a ridiculous amount of useless memory.  So will this code properly exit stage4 before calling stage5? Or should I fix the stage structure entirely to fix this problem?

Comment: Short answer: yes. The call to `stage5` will have to complete and resolve to a value before that value can be returned. Of course stage4 has to wait for that. If you want lazy evaluation, you'd have to e.g. return a callable using a `lambda`. However it's not clear to me what you think the *problem* is.

Comment: Oops, the question wasn't about condensing OP's code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the quick answer.  The problem is that for me to complete stage5, I will have stage4, stage3... and all the previous stages waiting for the value instead of terminating.  If I get to stage100 and I still have the values used for stage1, stage2, ..., stage99 stored, it seems like a big waste.  My goal is to transition between stages while making sure the previous one exits.

Comment: Then change your code so that the next step isn't called from within the current one; have something outside that orchestrates the process.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was thinking just that, but I wanted to make sure if it was necessary.  Wishful thinking got me thinking it might be fine....

Comment: Do you really have a "ridiculous amount of useless memory"? In your code snippet I only see one int.

Comment: And maybe ask whether Python does tail call elimination/optimization. That's what you want to know, isn't it? Or just google it.